# Streaming videos from embedded jetty in java ( Cannot skip to the minute i want )

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have a java application that uses embedded jetty to provide rest api. One of this rest api allows downloading a file given a certain id.

- The user can upload a file through an upload rest endpoint, at this point i save the file and store a record on the database containing a file id.
- Once uploaded you can access the file through the endpoint (GET) `server/api/v1/files/{fileId}`
- In that endpoint i do the following to provide the file:

```
String filePath = "/shared/files/fileId";
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", fileEntity.size + "");
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    out = response.getOutputStream();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) fileEntity.size];
    int bytesRead;


    while ((bytesRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}finally{
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

This works fine as long as i only try to download the file, and in the case of a video, if i access the endpoint in chrome, it displays the default page for viewing videos and the video stream starts. 
However, when i try to skip to minute 10 for example of a video i am streaming, the video just keeps playing without skipping to the time i choose.
Another problem is that randomly, for big files, the request times out even before displaying the video default page.
This is how i initialize embedded jetty:

```
ServletContextHandler contextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
contextHandler.setContextPath("/");
server = new Server(new QueuedThreadPool(10000, 10));

HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
httpConfig.setOutputBufferSize(1024);

ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server, new HttpConnectionFactory(httpConfig));
connector.setPort(port);

server.addConnector(connector);

ServletHolder jerseyServlet = contextHandler.addServlet(org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/api/v1/*");
jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "webapi");

FilterHolder filter = new FilterHolder(new CrossOriginFilter());
filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_ORIGINS_PARAM, "*");
filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_METHODS_PARAM, "POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,HEAD");
filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOWED_HEADERS_PARAM, "*");
filter.setInitParameter(CrossOriginFilter.ALLOW_CREDENTIALS_PARAM, "true");


contextHandler.addFilter(filter, "/*", EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));
contextHandler.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());

ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();

HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
handlerCollection.addHandler(contextHandler);
handlerCollection.addHandler(resourceHandler);

server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
```

And this is how the endpoints for the files are created:

```
@Path("/")
public class FilesRestService {

    @Context
    HttpServletRequest request;
    @Context
    SecurityContext securityContext;
    @Context
    HttpServletResponse response;

    @GET
    @Path("/files/{fileId}")
    public void download(@PathParam("fileId") String fileId) {
        getFilesImpl().downloadFile(fileId);
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/files/upload")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public Response uploadFile() {
        return getFilesImpl().uploadFile();
    }
}
```

Please feel free to even point out if i should completely change the approach.

Comment: Check the request that is issued when you attempt to "skip" to a later part of the video, it likely has a `Range` header, that you need to support in your implementation.

Comment: It does, but i do not see a request coming in every time i "skip". Also, how should i handle data stream based on the Range header? Do you know where i could start learning about its implementation?